# Receiving updates after filter deleted

Tags: support

I had a filter to email me Clojure posts, but a couple of days ago, I removed that filter. However, I keep getting email. Does the change take a few days, or is something else going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Deleting" a filter doesn't remove it from existence. It just removes the filter from your own list of filters. For example, your [deleted filter's permalink](https://stackexchange.com/filters/43586) still works.

To unsubscribe from the filter, click "unsubscribe" either in the email footer, or on your [network profile's subscriptions page](https://stackexchange.com/users/201953/octopusgrabbus?tab=subscriptions).

This behavior exists because it's possible to subscribe to other people's filters, and filter deletion shouldn't cause other people's subscriptions to break. Thinking about it now though, perhaps filter deletion behavior should be adjusted to automatically unsubscribe *you*, but nobody else.

Comment: *"Deleting" a filter doesn't remove it from existence.* - Good to know! Now I can go delete those filters I created for other people...

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly.